# QWC2: Webpage loading with all layers

Tags: qgis, qwc2

Whenever I run the qwc2 web client, all the layers in the theme get loaded under "Layers and Legends". How do I configure it so that only the layers I want get loaded upon initial loading of the web client. I am aware the "l" parameter in the URL could be modified to display the layers, but how do I configure it so that I don't have to manually change the URL each time? Are there any changes I can make to the themesConfig.json or config.json to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your QGIS project by removing/adding all the layers you want, and make it visible/hidden.

Then, copy the project in your QGIS Server projects directory. You should see your theme with only the layers you want at the loading of QWC2.